# Get selected value from dropdown menu, from an array?

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I feel like I am really missing something here. I did some manual customizations on a short (wordpress) script and try to set a `<select><option>` to "selected" if it has been selected. In order to accomplish this, I tried to find out if the `$term->id = similar` to the selected option value (which is an ID as well). All good so far, but I cannot seem to get the submitted `<select><option>`. All it says is 'array'.

Below is my script. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here? To be clear, it seems to be all about the `$_GET["listing_cat"]` here. Also when i try to print the `$_GET["listing_cat"]` within the `foreach` all it outputs is 'array'.

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo trailingslashit( home_url() ); ?>" class="custsearch">
<select name="listing_cat[]">
<option value="1" disabled="disabled" <?php if(!count($_GET)>0 || !$_GET["listing_cat"] ){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Pls choose</option>
        <?php
        $cat_args = array(
        'orderby'           => 'id', 
        'parent'        => 0,
        'hide_empty'    => false           
    );
        $terms = get_terms('listing_category', $cat_args );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            printf( '<option class="level-0" value="' . $term->term_id .'"');
            if($_GET["listing_cat"] == $term->term_id) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }
            printf( '>%s</option>', $term->slug, $term->name );
        }

        ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: this could be totally unrelated but you do realize you have brackets in the name of the select? that certainly makes me think it's interpreting the value should be an array. If it were a multi select it would be make sense that's its an array in the get, either way foeach on listing_cat, see what's in there

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is all that i needed.. quite logical;). I put it into a function and needed the in_array() to check:

```
//category in dropdown
function the_refine_category_ui2() {
    $cat_args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'id', 
    'parent'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'    => false           
);
    $terms = get_terms('listing_category', $cat_args ); 
foreach ($terms as $term) {

   printf( '<option class="level-0"');
   if( in_array( $term->term_id, $_GET["listing_cat"] )) { echo 'selected ';} 

    printf('value="' . $term->term_id .'"');
            printf( '>%s' . $term->term_id .'</option>', $term->slug, $term->name );


}
}
```